# Best way to handle Error on basic Array

Tags: scala, error-handling

```
val myArray = Array("1", "2")
val error = myArray(5)//throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException
```

`myArray` has no fixed size, which explains why a call like performed on the above second line might happen.

First, I never really understood the reasons to use `error handling` for expected errors. Am I wrong to consider this practice as bad, resulting from poor coding skills or an inclination towards laziness?

What would be the best way to handle the above case?

- What I am leaning towards: basic implementation (condition) to prevent accessing the data like depicted;
- use `Option`;
- use `Try` or `Either`;
- use a `try-catch` block.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for. Do you refer to the potential of an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` if you would do `myArray(5)` ? If so, how to handle that will depend on context. You can always check size and avoid the exception.

Comment: For any code that can throw an exception, you should wrap it in a `Try`. Then you can do whatever you want with that `Try`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 Avoid addressing elements through index

Scala offers a rich set of collection operations that are applied to Arrays through `ArrayOps` implicit conversions. This lets us use `combinators` like `map`, `flatMap`, `take`, `drop`, .... on arrays instead of addressing elements by index.

## 2 Prevent access out of range

An example I've seen often when parsing CSV-like data (in Spark):

```
case class Record(id:String, name: String, address:String)
val RecordSize = 3
val csvData = // some comma separated data
val records = csvData.map(line => line.split(","))
                     .collect{case arr if (arr.size == RecordSize) => 
                              Record(arr(0), arr(1), arr(2))}
```

## 3 Use checks that fit in the current context

If we are using monadic constructs to compose access to some resource, use a fitting way of lift errors to the application flow:
e.g. Imagine we are retrieving user preferences from some repository and we want the first one:

### Option

```
def getUserById(id:ID):Option[User]
def getPreferences(user:User) : Option[Array[Preferences]]

val topPreference = for {
      user <- userById(id)
      preferences <- getPreferences(user)
      topPreference <- preferences.lift(0)
   } yield topPreference
```

(or even better, applying advice #1):

```
val topPreference = for {
      user <- userById(id)
      preferences <- getPreferences(user)
      topPreference <- preferences.headOption
   } yield topPreference
```

### Try

```
def getUserById(id:ID): Try[User]
def getPreferences(user:User) : Try[Array[Preferences]]
val topPreference = for {
      user <- userById(id)
      preferences <- getPreferences(user)
      topPreference <- Try(preferences(0))
   } yield topPreference
```

As general guidance: Use the [principle of least power](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/StrategicScalaStylePrincipleofLeastPower.html).
If possible, use error-free combinators: = `array.drop(4).take(1)`
If all that matters is having an element or not, use `Option`
If we need to preserve the reason why we could not find an element, use `Try`.

Let the types and context of the program guide you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `arr.lift` (available in standard library) which returns `Option` instead of throwing exception.

*if not use `safely`*

Try to access the element `safely` to avoid accidentally throwing exceptions in middle of the code.

```
implicit class ArrUtils[T](arr: Array[T]) {
   import scala.util.Try
   def safely(index: Int): Option[T] = Try(arr(index)).toOption
}
```

Usage:

```
arr.safely(4)
```

**REPL**

```
scala> val arr = Array(1, 2, 3)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> implicit class ArrUtils[T](arr: Array[T]) {
   import scala.util.Try
   def safely(index: Int): Option[T] = Try(arr(index)).toOption
  }
defined class ArrUtils

scala> arr.safely(4)
res5: Option[Int] = None

scala> arr.safely(1)
res6: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If indexing `myArray` can be expected to error on occasion, then it sounds like `Option` would be the way to go.

```
myArray.lift(1)  // Option[String] = Some(2)
myArray.lift(5)  // Option[String] = None
```

You could use `Try()` but why bother if you already know what the error is and you're not interested in catching or reporting it?